# How to get response from S3 getObject in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

In a Node.js project I am attempting to get data back from S3.

When I use `getSignedURL`, everything works:

```
aws.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function(err, url){
    console.log(url); 
});
```

My params are:

```
var params = {
              Bucket: "test-aws-imagery", 
              Key: "TILES/Level4/A3_B3_C2/A5_B67_C59_Tiles.par"
```

If I take the URL output to the console and paste it in a web browser, it downloads the file I need.

However, if I try to use `getObject` I get all sorts of odd behavior.  I believe I am just using it incorrectly.  This is what I've tried:

```
aws.getObject(params, function(err, data){
    console.log(data); 
    console.log(err); 
});
```

Outputs:

```
{ 
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 'Wed, 06 Apr 2016 20:04:02 GMT',
  ContentLength: '1602862',
  ETag: '9826l1e5725fbd52l88ge3f5v0c123a4"',
  ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer 01 00 00 00  ... > }

  null
```

So it appears that this is working properly.  However, when I put a breakpoint on one of the `console.log`s, my IDE (NetBeans) throws an error and refuses to show the value of data. While this could just be the IDE, I decided to try other ways to use `getObject`.

```
aws.getObject(params).on('httpData', function(chunk){
    console.log(chunk); 
}).on('httpDone', function(data){
    console.log(data); 
});
```

This does not output anything.  Putting a breakpoint in shows that the code never reaches either of the `console.log`s.  I also tried:

```
aws.getObject(params).on('success', function(data){
    console.log(data); 
});
```

However, this also does not output anything and placing a breakpoint shows that the `console.log` is never reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `aws` object actually a new instance of the `aws.S3` object? Also, is the response from `getObject()`being passed back to a http response or is it is being piped to a file?

Comment: @peteb `aws = new AWS.S3()`. The response should not be piped to a file. I need to use it in the Javascript

Comment: So then is it safe to assume that the contents are JSON or XML?

Comment: @peteb neither, they are a custom file format

Comment: Show the params you are using in the `getObject()` call. If you are trying to pass a signed URL to getObject I don't think that will work.

Comment: @peteb editted to show params

Answer (score 341, accepted):

### @aws-sdk/client-s3 (2022 Update)

Since I wrote this answer in 2016, Amazon has released a new JavaScript SDK, [`@aws-sdk/client-s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html). This new version improves on the original `getObject()` by returning a promise always instead of opting in via `.promise()` being chained to `getObject()`. In addition to that, [`response.Body`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectcommandoutput.html#body) is no longer a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) but, one of `Readable|ReadableStream|Blob`. This changes the handling of the `response.Data` a bit. This should be more performant since we can stream the data returned instead of holding all of the contents in memory, with the trade-off being that it is a bit more verbose to implement.

In the below example the `response.Body` data will be streamed into an array and then returned as a string. This is the equivalent example of my original answer. Alternatively, the `response.Body` could use [`stream.Readable.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) to an HTTP Response, a File or any other type of [`stream.Writeable`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) for further usage, this would be the more performant way when getting large objects.

If you wanted to use a `Buffer`, like the original `getObject()` response, this can be done by wrapping `responseDataChunks` in a [`Buffer.concat()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) instead of using [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), this would be useful when interacting with binary data. To note, since `Array#join()` returns a string, each `Buffer` instance in `responseDataChunks` will have [`Buffer.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) called implicitly and the default encoding of `utf8` will be used.

```
const { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
const client = new S3Client() // Pass in opts to S3 if necessary

function getObject (Bucket, Key) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key })

    try {
      const response = await client.send(getObjectCommand)
  
      // Store all of data chunks returned from the response data stream 
      // into an array then use Array#join() to use the returned contents as a String
      let responseDataChunks = []

      // Handle an error while streaming the response body
      response.Body.once('error', err => reject(err))
  
      // Attach a 'data' listener to add the chunks of data to our array
      // Each chunk is a Buffer instance
      response.Body.on('data', chunk => responseDataChunks.push(chunk))
  
      // Once the stream has no more data, join the chunks into a string and return the string
      response.Body.once('end', () => resolve(responseDataChunks.join('')))
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle the error or throw
      return reject(err)
    } 
  })
}
```

##### Comments on using `Readable.toArray()`

Using [`Readable.toArray()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readabletoarrayoptions) instead of working with the stream events directly might be more convenient to use but, its worse performing. It works by reading all response data chunks into memory before moving on. Since this removes all benefits of streaming, this approach is discouraged per the Node.js docs.

> As this method reads the entire stream into memory, it negates the benefits of streams. It's intended for interoperability and convenience, not as the primary way to consume streams. [Documentation Link](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readabletoarrayoptions)

##### `@aws-sdk/client-s3` Documentation Links

- [`GetObjectCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjectcommand.html)
- [`GetObjectCommandInput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectcommandinput.html)
- [`GetObjectCommandOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectcommandoutput.html)

### aws-sdk (Original Answer)

When doing a `getObject()` from the S3 API, per the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) the contents of your file are located in the `Body` property, which you can see from your sample output. You should have code that looks something like the following

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3(); // Pass in opts to S3 if necessary

var getParams = {
    Bucket: 'abc', // your bucket name,
    Key: 'abc.txt' // path to the object you're looking for
}

s3.getObject(getParams, function(err, data) {
    // Handle any error and exit
    if (err)
        return err;

  // No error happened
  // Convert Body from a Buffer to a String
  let objectData = data.Body.toString('utf-8'); // Use the encoding necessary
});
```

You may not need to create a new buffer from the `data.Body` object but if you need you can use the sample above to achieve that.

Comment: So the data coming back does seem to be a `Buffer` object, which I'm not familiar with. Theoretically I could use `new Buffer(data.Body).toString('utf-8');` to get to the content?

Comment: If the content is already a Buffer, no need to create a new Buffer from that. Simply just do `data.Body.toString('utf-8');`. A Buffer is a representation of Binary data in node, if you need more info [here are the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

Comment: Thank you! This would be so much easier to work through if I could actually get a breakpoint working.  For whatever reason (and this is the only place I've had this happen), within the function Netbeans refuses to show any variable values

Comment: This works for text, but is there a generic solution for handling text files as well as .png, .jpg, etc.?

Comment: @carter This is a general solution. Just change the `.toString('utf8')` when accessing `data.Body` to `.toString('binary')` if you want a binary string for images. If the `Buffer` in `data.Body` doesn't need to be converted to a String like in this question, then you can just return `data.Body` and work with the `Buffer` directly.

Comment: "Convert Body from a Buffer to a String"... would be great if the AWS docs made this a bit more clear. I'm getting pretty fed up wrestling with AWS.

Comment: It is absolutely insane that I can't find any documentation within AWS docs or on their NPM repo that just has this code.  Like, did they really have to make it that hard?  They couldn't just have a "for dummies" method (or even a stupid command class) that just gets the file contents b64 encoded or something with the rest of the object data?  Like it grabs an absurd amount of garbage metadata that I, and I imagine most people, will NEVER NEED.  But it can't return the object data itself?

Comment: @peteb, your 2021 Update saved me after two days of being stuck on this exact problem. I ended up using a Buffer.concat() as per your suggestion to get a Buffer (which I later displayed as a Base64 image following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699628/how-to-convert-a-file-buffer-to-img-tag-src). Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the section: "Comments on using Readable.toArray()". @peteb's implementation does the same exact thing by pushing each chunk into an array, it's just Readable.toArray() reimplemented.

Comment: @JoeFlateau If you're only copying the exact code in my example, then yes, there is functional parity between the two approaches. However, the nuance to my commentary is, don't naively use the method assuming its equivalent to working with the stream directly. For instance, if `getObject()` is invoked in a route, it would be best to use `readable.pipe()` instead of following my sample code. It's the highest performing approach, I mention this in my answer prior to the example. If you're building something that has wide variances in the size of files, stick with streaming.

Answer (score 73):

Based on the answer by @peteb, but using `Promises` and `Async/Await`:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

async function getObject (bucket, objectKey) {
  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: objectKey 
    }

    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    return data.Body.toString('utf-8');
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Could not retrieve file from S3: ${e.message}`)
  }
}

// To retrieve you need to use `await getObject()` or `getObject().then()`
const myObject = await getObject('my-bucket', 'path/to/the/object.txt');
```

Comment: The .promise() on the end of getObject() was the key for me. I find the AWS SDK a little unintuitive at times.

Comment: My response is saying 'Promise { <pending> }'

Comment: @jonask `getObject()` is an async function, did you try calling it with `await getObject(...)`?

Answer (score 22):

### Updated (2022)

nodejs [v17.5.0 added](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/41553) [Readable.toArray](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readabletoarrayoptions). If this API is available in your node version. The code will be very short:

```
const buffer = Buffer.concat(
    await (
        await s3Client
            .send(new GetObjectCommand({
                Key: '<key>',
                Bucket: '<bucket>',
            }))
    ).Body.toArray()
)
```

If you are using Typescript, you are safe to cast the `.Body` part as `Readable` (the other types `ReadableStream` and `Blob` are only returned in browser environment. Moreover, in browser, `Blob` [is only used](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/b0e1422630bbdc6842f7b91629d1ff66693e0fde/packages/fetch-http-handler/src/fetch-http-handler.ts#L79) in legacy fetch API when [`response.body`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_response_body) is not supported)

```
(response.Body as Readable).toArray()
```

Note that: `Readable.toArray` is an experimental (yet handy) feature, use it with caution.

[image]

=============

### Original answer

If you are using aws sdk v3, the sdk v3 returns nodejs [Readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) (precisely, [IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage) which extends Readable) instead of a Buffer.

Here is a Typescript version. Note that this is for node only, if you send the request from browser, check the longer answer in the blog post mentioned below.

```
import {GetObjectCommand, S3Client} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import type {Readable} from 'stream'

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    region: 'us-west-2',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: '<access key>',
        secretAccessKey: '<access secret>',
    }
})
const response = await s3Client
    .send(new GetObjectCommand({
        Key: '<key>',
        Bucket: '<bucket>',
    }))
const stream = response.Body as Readable

return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks: Buffer[] = []
    stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
    stream.once('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)))
    stream.once('error', reject)
})
// if readable.toArray() is support
// return Buffer.concat(await stream.toArray())
```

Why do we have to cast `response.Body as Readable`? The answer is too long. Interested readers can find more information on [my blog post](https://transang.me/modern-fetch-and-how-to-get-buffer-output-from-aws-sdk-v3-getobjectcommand/).

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful! You can also use a for await loop as an alternative:
```ts
    const readable = (await s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key, ...options })).Body as Readable;
    const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
    for await (const chunk of readable) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    return Buffer.concat(chunks);
```

Answer (score 9):

For someone looking for a `NEST JS TYPESCRIPT` version of the above:

```
    /**
     * to fetch a signed URL of a file
     * @param key key of the file to be fetched
     * @param bucket name of the bucket containing the file
     */
    public getFileUrl(key: string, bucket?: string): Promise<string> {
        var scopeBucket: string = bucket ? bucket : this.defaultBucket;
        var params: any = {
            Bucket: scopeBucket,
            Key: key,
            Expires: signatureTimeout  // const value: 30
        };
        return this.account.getSignedUrlPromise(getSignedUrlObject, params);
    }

    /**
     * to get the downloadable file buffer of the file
     * @param key key of the file to be fetched
     * @param bucket name of the bucket containing the file
     */
    public async getFileBuffer(key: string, bucket?: string): Promise<Buffer> {
        var scopeBucket: string = bucket ? bucket : this.defaultBucket;
        var params: GetObjectRequest = {
            Bucket: scopeBucket,
            Key: key
        };
        var fileObject: GetObjectOutput = await this.account.getObject(params).promise();
        return Buffer.from(fileObject.Body.toString());
    }

    /**
     * to upload a file stream onto AWS S3
     * @param stream file buffer to be uploaded
     * @param key key of the file to be uploaded
     * @param bucket name of the bucket 
     */
    public async saveFile(file: Buffer, key: string, bucket?: string): Promise<any> {
        var scopeBucket: string = bucket ? bucket : this.defaultBucket;
        var params: any = {
            Body: file,
            Bucket: scopeBucket,
            Key: key,
            ACL: 'private'
        };
        var uploaded: any = await this.account.upload(params).promise();
        if (uploaded && uploaded.Location && uploaded.Bucket === scopeBucket && uploaded.Key === key)
            return uploaded;
        else {
            throw new HttpException("Error occurred while uploading a file stream", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Comment: fileObject.Body returns either Buffer or undefined, and not able to return it using typescript

Answer (score 9):

### Converting `GetObjectOutput.Body` to `Promise<string>` using node-fetch

In aws-sdk-js-v3 @aws-sdk/client-s3, [`GetObjectOutput.Body`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectcommandoutput.html#body) is a subclass of [`Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) in nodejs (specifically an instance of [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage)) instead of a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer) as it was in [aws-sdk v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property), so `resp.Body.toString('utf-8')` will give you the wrong result “[object Object]”. Instead, the easiest way to turn `GetObjectOutput.Body` into a `Promise<string>` is to construct a node-fetch [`Response`](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#new-responsebody-options), which takes a `Readable` subclass (or `Buffer` instance, or other [types from the fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract)) and has conversion methods `.json()`, `.text()`, `.arrayBuffer()`, and `.blob()`.

This should also work in the other variants of aws-sdk and platforms (@aws-sdk v3 node `Buffer`, v3 browser `Uint8Array` subclass, v2 node `Readable`, v2 browser `ReadableStream` or `Blob`)

```sh
npm install node-fetch
```

```
import { Response } from 'node-fetch';
import * as s3 from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const client = new s3.S3Client({})
const s3Response = await client.send(new s3.GetObjectCommand({Bucket: '…', Key: '…'});
const response = new Response(s3Response.Body);

const obj = await response.json();
// or
const text = await response.text();
// or
const buffer = Buffer.from(await response.arrayBuffer());
// or
const blob = await response.blob();
```

Reference: [`GetObjectOutput.Body` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectcommandoutput.html#body), [node-fetch `Response` documentation](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/tree/main#new-responsebody-options), [node-fetch `Body` constructor source](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/v3.1.0/src/body.js#L51), [minipass-fetch `Body` constructor source](https://github.com/npm/minipass-fetch/blob/v1.4.1/lib/body.js#L29)

Thanks to [kennu comment in `GetObjectCommand` usability issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-793028742)

Comment: cant thank enough of this answer. However, I did few extra steps in order to read it. 1. installed version 2.6 of node-fetch (as v3 requires in ESM) 2. install @types/node-fetch if you are using typescript.

Answer (score 8):

Just as an alternate solution:

As per this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-1287275227) on the same subject, it seems like in October 2022, there is a way of handling the body returned from an S3 GetObject request. Assuming you are using AWS SDK V3, you can take advantage of the `@aws-sdk/util-stream-node` package in the official AWS SDK:

```js
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { sdkStreamMixin } from '@aws-sdk/util-stream-node';

const s3Client = new S3Client({});
const { Body } = await s3Client.send(
  new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'your-bucket',
    Key: 'your-key',
  }),
);

// Throws error if Body is undefined
const body = await sdkStreamMixin(Body).transformToString();
```

You can also transform the body into a byte array or web stream using the `.transformToByteArray()` and `.transformToWebStream()` functions.

Keep in mind that the package says that [you shouldn't be using it directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_stream_node.html#sdkstreammixin-1), but it seems to be the most straightforward way to handle the body from the request.

This was found in [this reply](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-1287275227) that highlighted a PR that added this feature.

Comment: @aws-sdk/util-stream-node is deprecated, @smithy/util-stream can be used instead

Answer (score 6):

Extremely similar answer to @ArianAcosta above. Except I'm using `import` (for Node 12.x and up), adding AWS config and sniffing for an image payload and applying `base64` processing to the `return`.

```js
// using v2.x of aws-sdk
import aws from 'aws-sdk'

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: "us-east-1" // or whatever
})

const s3 = new aws.S3();

/**
 * getS3Object()
 * 
 * @param { string } bucket - the name of your bucket
 * @param { string } objectKey - object you are trying to retrieve
 * @returns { string } - data, formatted
 */
export async function getS3Object (bucket, objectKey) {
  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: objectKey 
    }

    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    // Check for image payload and formats appropriately
    if( data.ContentType === 'image/jpeg' ) {
      return data.Body.toString('base64');
    } else {
      return data.Body.toString('utf-8');
    }

  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Could not retrieve file from S3: ${e.message}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**AWS-SDK V3 Easy solution**

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const getS3Object = async (record): Promise<string> => {
  const client = new S3Client();
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'bucket_name',
    Key: 'object_key'
  });
  let output = '';
  const response = await client.send(command);
  output = await response.Body.transformToString();
  return output;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

At first glance it doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong but you don't show all your code. The following worked for me when I was first checking out S3 and Node:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

if (typeof process.env.API_KEY == 'undefined') {
    var config = require('./config.json');
    for (var key in config) {
        if (config.hasOwnProperty(key)) process.env[key] = config[key];
    }
}

var s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID, secretAccessKey:process.env.AWS_KEY});
var objectPath = process.env.AWS_S3_FOLDER +'/test.xml';
s3.putObject({
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET, 
    Key: objectPath,
    Body: "<rss><data>hello Fred</data></rss>",
    ACL:'public-read'
}, function(err, data){
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        console.log(data);           // successful response
        s3.getObject({
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET, 
            Key: objectPath
        }, function(err, data){
            console.log(data.Body.toString());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could use [minio-js client library](https://github.com/minio/minio-js) **get-object.js**

```
var Minio = require('minio')

var s3Client = new Minio({
  endPoint: 's3.amazonaws.com',
  accessKey: 'YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
  secretKey: 'YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY'
})

var size = 0
// Get a full object.
s3Client.getObject('my-bucketname', 'my-objectname', function(e, dataStream) {
  if (e) {
    return console.log(e)
  }
  dataStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    size += chunk.length
  })
  dataStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log("End. Total size = " + size)
  })
  dataStream.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  })
})
```

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io) Its open source, S3 compatible object storage written in golang with client libraries available in [Java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java), [Python](https://github.com/minio/minio-python), [Js](https://github.com/minio/minio-js), [golang](https://github.com/minio/minio-go).

Comment: Tried mino, but how to get buffer data, when I print dataStream.Body its giving 'undefined'. 


ie   console.log('datastream', dataStream.Body); //undefined

Answer (score 1):

The Body.toString() method no longer works with the latest version of the s3 api. Use the following instead:

```js
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const streamToString = (stream) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks = [];
      stream.on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
      stream.on("error", reject);
      stream.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("utf8")));
    });

(async () => {
  const region = "us-west-2";
  const client = new S3Client({ region });

  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: "test-aws-sdk-js-1877",
    Key: "readme.txt",
  });

  const { Body } = await client.send(command);
  const bodyContents = await streamToString(Body);
  console.log(bodyContents);
})();
```

Copy and pasted from here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-755387549

Not sure why this solution hasn't already been added as I think it is cleaner than the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using new version of the SDK and Typescript

```
const params = {
                Bucket: bucketName,
                Key: item.Key
            }

            s3.send(new GetObjectCommand(params))
                .then(async data => {
                    fs.writeFileSync(`./${folderName}/${item.Key?.split('/').pop()}`, await data.Body!.transformToString('utf-8'))
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using express and AWS SDK v3:

```
  public downloadFeedFile = (req: IFeedUrlRequest, res: Response) => {
    const downloadParams: GetObjectCommandInput = parseS3Url(req.s3FileUrl.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    logger.info("requesting S3 file  " + JSON.stringify(downloadParams));
    const run = async () => {
      try {
        const fileStream = await this.s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(downloadParams));
        if (fileStream.Body instanceof Readable){
          fileStream.Body.once('error', err => {
            console.error("Error downloading s3 file")
            console.error(err);
          });

          fileStream.Body.pipe(res);

        }
      } catch (err) {
        logger.error("Error", err);
      }
    };

  run();

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is for aws-sdk v3 version:**

If you need s3 reponse in json, you may try this solution:

```
const { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const s3 = new S3Client({});


async function getS3Config() {
    const params = {
        Bucket: "abc_bucket",
        Key: 'sample.json'
    }

    try {
        const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
        const { Body } = await s3.send(command);
        let result = await streamToString(Body);
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}



const streamToString = (stream) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    stream.on('error', reject);
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')));
});
```

streamToString function is for transforming streams to chunks and concat when response is done

Answer (score -1):

This is the `async` / `await` version

```
var getObjectAsync = async function(bucket,key) {
  try {
    const data = await s3
      .getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key })
      .promise();
      var contents = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
      return contents;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
var getObject = async function(bucket,key) {
    const contents = await getObjectAsync(bucket,key);
    console.log(contents.length);
    return contents;
}
getObject(bucket,key);
```