# accessing serialized contents of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am accessing the xml file from the S3 bucket using

```
var params = {
  Bucket: "bucketName", 
  Key: "xmlFileName.xml"
 };

 s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) 
 {
   if (!err) 
   {
       console.log(data);
   }
}
```

If I open up the comment in the log I get

```
 2017-12-21T04:23:53.991Z   bf6be172-e606-11e7-97cb-2139c6f9555f    { AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
LastModified: 2017-12-19T01:33:35.000Z,
ContentLength: 119567,
ETag: '"88764498c11c434213fb3929235a12a5"',
ContentType: 'text/xml',
Metadata: {},
Body: <Buffer 3c 42 4c 5f 50 65 72 73 6f 6e 6e 65 6c 52 65 70 6c 69 63 61 74 65 20 78 6d 6c 6e 73 3a 69 3d 22 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 77 33 2e 6f 72 67 2f ... > } undefined
```

Im assuming the content of the body is the serialized contents of the Xml file...Now how do I store this in a variable?

Ive tried

```
data.body
data[0].body
```

both coming back as undefined.

Please advise

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942442/how-to-get-response-from-s3-getobject-in-node-js/36944450

Comment: try finding out what data is.  YOu can type "typeof data" in the javascript console

Comment: data.body is buffer try data.body.toString() may help

Answer (score 0):

Try data.Body (capital letter). It's a Buffer so you'll need to convert it to a String before parsing the XML - try:

```
var xmlString = data.Body.toString()
```