# Reading data from s3: s3.getObject is not a function

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to read a txt file from S3 to build a response for Alexa.  When testing the code in Lambda, i am getting this error.  Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Error

```
Error handled: s3.getObject is not a function
```

I have installed the 'aws-sdk' and required the module at the top of my skill's index.js

```
const s3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')
```

Handler code.   Just to highlight the point, i am using Async/Await and returning a Promise in the goGetS3 function below.

```
const ChooseStoryIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'ChooseStoryIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    let speechText;
    let options = {
      "Bucket": "stores",
      "Key": "person.txt"
    }
    await goGetS3(options)
      .then((response) =&gt; {
        console.log(response),
        console.log(response.Body.toString()),
          speechText = response
      })
      .catch((err) =&gt; {
        console.log(err)
        speechText = 'something wrong getting the story'
      })
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

goGetS3() function code.  I tried two different versions of it, both give me the same error above.

```
const goGetS3 = function (options) {
    s3.getObject(options, function (err, data) {
      //handle error
      if (err) {
        reject("Error", err);
      }
      //success
      if (data) {
        resolve(data.Body.toString())
      }
    }).promise()
}
// const goGetS3 = function (options) {
//   return new Promise((resolve, reject) =&gt; {
//     s3.getObject(options, function (err, data) {
//       //handle error
//       if (err) {
//         reject("Error", err);
//       }
//       //success
//       if (data) {
//         resolve(data.Body.toString())
//       }
//     })
//   })
// }
```

My code is assembled from the following blogs/articles.

- The hello-world skill template using ask new cli
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1436
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942442/how-to-get-response-from-s3-getobject-in-node-js
- #### https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

**#### EDIT ###**

As per @milan-cermak i added this at the top of the page

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
```

but now get this error

```
module initialization error: TypeError 
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:6:12) 
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:565:32) 
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3) 
at Module.require (module.js:596:17) 
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `s3` in your code is not the instance of the S3 client, but just the module. You need to create a new instance of the client first.

```js
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
const s3 = new S3();

// you can now do s3.getObject
```

Comment: Hi Milan, i added this at the top of the page,

`const AWS = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')
const s3 = new AWS.S3();`

but now get this error


`module initialization error: TypeError
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)`

Answer (score 3):

To get this to work, i had to change

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
```

to

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
```

I would love to know why i needed to import the entire AWS SDK to get this to work..