# nodejs how to get JSON instead of Buffer from aws s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a .json file stored in a S3 Bucket,
now i Want to download the json File with nodejs.
I wrote following Code:

```js
const bucket = "s3bucketname";

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3= new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var transcript = await download();
    console.log(transcript);
}

async function download(){
  try {
    // Converted it to async/await syntax just to simplify.
    const data = await S3.getObject(
    {   Bucket: bucket, 
        Key: "Test.json",
        //ResponseContentType: 'application/json'
    }).promise();

    console.log(data);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 400,
      body: err.message || JSON.stringify(err.message)
    }
  }
}
```

My Response is like this:
AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2020-02-07T08:04:25.000Z,
  ContentLength: 12723,
  ETag: '"ea7de645f93c45b3jkj4e7ffjdsf"',
  ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: Buffer 7b 0d ...

In the body i get a Buffer from my JSON, if I convert it via tools like:
https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-bytes-to-utf8

I get my JSON string like i want it. How can i do that in Javascript/nodejs ?
I don't need the Buffer, I need the JSON in String. I tried different ways, but it didnt work yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to do `data.Body.toString('utf-8')` to get the proper json (string version) from buffer.

Comment: if i change body: JSON.stringify(data.toString()),

I get body: ' " [object Object]" '
how can i access to the string version of the json ?

Comment: If you have the "[object Object]" value, you may use the new version of the sdk and need to update your code to download the data as chunks > https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944450/4912329

Answer (score 40):

I don't have the reputation to add comment for @Ashish Modi's answer.
The **data.Body.toString('utf-8')** will convert it to plain string not to json object.
If you want to have the json object you can convert the string to json object by
**JSON.parse(obj.Body.toString('utf-8'))**

Comment: Confirming this works for me too, this will also parse if you are returning an array of json objects from a json file if that makes sense, it will parse it in as an array.

Comment: now u do have the reputation :-) cheers!