# Read JSON file stored in aws S3 with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-s3

I managed to read a JSON file stored in my S3 bucket but I'm having to do a lot of transformation that I dont fully understand.

If we log the data as it comes we get an output of Buffer data

```
s3.getObject(objParam, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  
  console.log(" ~ file: reader.js ~ line 31 ~ rs ~ data", data.Body)

});

// outputs  data <Buffer 7b 0a 20 20 22 74 79 70 65 22 3a 20 22 42 75 66 66 ...
```

If we convert the above buffer to string with toString('utf-8') I get this:

```
data.Body.toString('utf8')

// outputs:
{
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    123,
    34,
    99,
    115,
    112,
    45,
    114,
    101,
    112,
    111,
    114,
....
```

The only way I managed to see my actual original JSON was converting the above to JSON, accessing the data property, creating a new buffer, then converting back again to toString('utf-8').

```
s3.getObject(objParam, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  const jsonBytes = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString('utf-8'));
  const buffer = Buffer.from(jsonBytes.data);
  const bufferBackToString = buffer.toString('utf-8');
  console.log(" ~ file: reader.js ~ line 21 ~ s3.getObject ~ bufferBackToString", bufferBackToString);

});

// output: Logs my original JSON!
{
"myProperty": "myData"
} // or whatever...
```

If it was already a buffer, why did I have to convert to one and convert back again to string? Could the buffer have different encoding?

Comment: What happens if you just do `data.toString()` to start instead of `data.Body.toString('utf-8')`?

Comment: Same thing if you pass utf-8

Comment: No, I meant without the `.Body`, just data.toString() or data.toString('utf-8') (although utf8 is default so you shouldn't need it afaik)

Comment: it prints  [object Object]... the stuff I need is inside data.Body, there are some other unrelated properties that I dont need in data

Comment: Ah, okay. Try the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942442/how-to-get-response-from-s3-getobject-in-node-js

Answer (score 2):

```
const getJsonFromS3 = async (filename, bucketName) => {
  const s3Output = await s3.getObject({
    Key: filename,
    Bucket: bucketName
  })

  try {
    const jsonString = await s3Output.Body?.transformToString()
    const json = JSON.parse(jsonString ?? '')
    return json
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error parsing json', error)
    return null
  }
}
```

all suggestions with `data.toString('utf-8')` not working for me.
but using `transformToString()` worked for me

Comment: And `data.toString('binary')` will preserve binary data.
This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const jsonBytes = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString('utf-8'));
console.log(jsonBytes);
```

worked for me , I did see in forums ,
that s3.getObject returns json directly not string

Answer (score 1):

fulfilling the answer of @JBird, the function is structured in a proper way but it have some errors that might affect the behavior.

```js
const getJsonFromS3 = async (filename, bucketName) => {
  const s3Output = await s3.getObject({
    Key: filename,
    Bucket: bucketName
  }).promise()

  try {
    const json = await s3Output.Body.toJSON()
    const { data } = json
    let arr1 = new Uint8Array(data); 
    let result = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr1))
    return result
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error parsing json', error)
    return null
  }
}
```

1. The 'getObject' function from the aws sdk it works by passing a callback into the function, you just need to add '.promise()' at the end to work as a promise
2. We received a bite array as response of the getObject function so we must treat it in that way