# How to read JSON file using the getObject command of AWS S3 Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to read a JSON file stored in an S3 bucket. I am trying to get the JSON file contents using getObject command of Javascript SDK. I am getting output as [object Object] when I convert the aws response to utf8 string. This is my nodeJS code:

```
const s3Client = require("./aws_s3_connect");
const { GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
//const storage_file_path = "";

const run = async (input_data) => {

    const bucket_name = "bucket_name";
    const file_path = "";
    const file_name = "sample.json";

    const bucketParams = {
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Key: file_path + file_name,
        ResponseContentType: 'application/json'
    };

    try {
        // Send get object command
        let aws_response = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams));
        console.log(aws_response);
        //var blob = new Blob(aws_response.Body);
        let data = aws_response.Body.toString('utf8');
        console.log(data);

        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
};

module.exports = { run };
```

Please help me to identify the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get response from S3 getObject in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942442/how-to-get-response-from-s3-getobject-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks. I am able to read the json using the response you shared.

Answer (score 1):

**Working example**

FROM 22/08/2023 you can use the built-in function `transformToString`

And assuming you have a bucket and a file/object ready

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
const s3 = new S3Client({region: "eu-west-1"});

const params = {Bucket: "my-unique-bucket", Key: "my-s3-object"};
const res = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand(params));
const bodyString = await res.Body.transformToString();
```

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_GetObject_section.html